# How to get the value of a key within an nested object array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, nested

I've been trying to learn PHP arrays, I have got the basic but struggling with this one.

I'm looking to try and get the value of a key "pdfUrl" by calling the key I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Array
(
[0] => Clearbooks_Soap_1_0_Invoice Object
    (
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Clearbooks_Soap_1_0_Item Object
                    (
                        [description] => Line Item #1
                        [unitPrice] => 24.99
                        [vat] => 5
                        [quantity] => 1
                        [type] => 1001001
                        [vatRate] => 0.2
                    )

            )

        [description] => API Test Invoice
        [entityId] => 16
        [invoice_id] => 209
        [invoice_prefix] => INV
        [invoiceNumber] => 204
        [reference] =>
        [dateCreated] => 2012-10-19 00:00:00
        [dateDue] => 2012-11-16 00:00:00
        [dateAccrual] => 2012-10-19 00:00:00
        [creditTerms] => 30
        [bankPaymentId] => 0
        [project] => 0
        [external_id] =>
        [status] => approved
        [pdfUrl] => https://secure.clearbooks.co.uk/accounting/sales/invoice_html/?source=statement&type=invoice&c=2&auth=-lHLOCMD8mOPS5qyEjiw2g
        [themeId] => 0
        [type] => S
        [vatTreatment] =>
        [multicurrency] => 0
        [gross] => 29.99
        [net] => 24.99
        [vat] => 5
        [paid] => 0
        [balance] => 29.99
        [foreignCurrencyBalance] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You start out with an array with only one object. To call this object you can use:

```
$nameVar[0]
```

Then we have an object. You can not use '[]' for objects in PHP. Use '->' to get the value of properties of an object:

```
$nameVar[0]->pdfUrl
```

So if we want the unitprice of the first item we use:

```
$nameVar[0]->items[0]->unitPrice
```

Comment: Absolute legend, thank you very much. Something so simple and I was over thinking it like crazy hahaha.